# JavaScript RegExp exclude specific file extension and index.js

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

This is my current RegExp:

```
/^(?!index).*js/gmi
```

This is the list the RegExp is applied to:

```
test/test.js
hey/test-bundle.js
test/test-heybundle.js
test/index.js
test/indop.js
lollipop/testindex.js
test/test.scss
test/test.css
lalilu/hey.yml
test.js
```

What it should do:

- Only match files ending with *.js
- Exclude the filename index.js
- Exclude files ending with "-bundle.js"
- Only match files that are located in a directory (e.g. `/test/test.js`, not `test.js`)

I'd really much appreciate any help to get this RegExp to work like expected.

Comment: Couldn't get the bundle part to match. Far is got was `^.*\/(?!index).*\.js` - that solves everything but the bundle part

Comment: Thanks! This is a good starting point for someone else.

Comment: Is it not possible to run through multiple regex in your use case?

Comment: `^(?=[^.]+\.js$)(?=[^/]+\/)(?!.*(?:index|-bundle)\.js).*$` https://regex101.com/r/Yqaajy/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/^[a-z]+\/(?!index\.js$)[a-z]+(?!-bundle)(?:-[a-z]+)?\.js$/gm`

https://regex101.com/r/Yqaajy/1

`^[a-z]+\/` - Match a parent directory (assuming the dir separator will always be a `/`).

`(?!index\.js$)` - Fail the match if the parent dir is followed by `index.js` and the end of the line.

`[a-z]+(?!-bundle)` - One or more letters not followed by `-bundle`.

`(?:-[a-z]+)?` - Optional 2nd part of the file name following a hyphen. Change the `?` to a `*` if you also have files that contain more than 2 hyphenated sections.

`\.js$` - File extension and end of line.

Comment: I've just noticed on "bug", even when using `*` for filenames with more than 2 dashes like you've suggested: https://regex101.com/r/Yqaajy/3 It should not match the penultimate line

Comment: Also I'm having problems matching files located in subdirectories: https://regex101.com/r/Yqaajy/4